# How can I properly invite people to a chat room so I can ask for resources?

Tags: support, chat

I created [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37419/books-resources) since it's not clear to me what's on topic or not in this SE site, and in most sites asking for resources, books, recommendations, ... is not on-topic.

Should I use meta for this? How can I invite people to join? (In both senses: is there an efficient way? what's SE-legal to do in this cases?)

Comment: You might try asking around in our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm)